# Get individual image src and title for Pinterest in prettyPhoto plugin?

Tags: jquery, lightbox, prettyphoto, pinterest

Pinterest is for individual photo images rather than web page URLs. Twitter and Facebook are fine with just the page URL but for Pinterest, each and every individual image URL should be supplied to the "Pin It" button link instead of the page URL.

I'm trying to add Pin It button to the prettyPhoto plugin and thus far everything's set except I don't know how to get the img src and title of each of the individual images in the slide so as to attach them in the "Pint It" link.

What I currently have immediately after the facebook code in jquery.prettyPhoto.js:

```
<div class="pinterest">
    <a href="http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url='+window.location.href+'&media='+$('#fullResImage').attr('src')+'&description='+$(this).attr('title')+'" class="pin-it-button" count-layout="horizontal" target="_blank">
        <img border="0" src="http://assets.pinterest.com/images/PinExt.png" title="Pin It" />
    </a>
</div>
```

But neither **$('#fullResImage').attr('src')** nor **$(this).attr('title')** are working correctly for some reason. You can view the [page here](http://www.avivaly.com/product/silk-wedding-dress-the-princess-bride/#!lightbox%5Bgallery%5D/2/), the script is [here](http://avivaly.com/wp-content/themes/mystile/includes/js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js). They are 'undefined' and empty.

Can someone please help me get them working? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as you all knows that Pinterest is for individual photo images rather than web page URLs, so we need to do something different like this,

```
<a href="http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url='+encodeURIComponent(location.href.replace(location.hash,""))+'&media={path}&description={title}" class="pin-it-button" count-layout="horizontal" target="_blank">
    <img border="0" src="http://assets.pinterest.com/images/PinExt.png" title="Pin It" />
</a>
```

this will not work here on prettyphoto gallery, so now here is the solution,

we have to use the code in script.js when we initialize the prettyphoto.

like this, code

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(‘.prettyPhoto’).prettyPhoto({
        changepicturecallback: onPictureChanged,
    });

    function onPictureChanged() {

    var href= “http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=”‘+ encodeURIComponent(location.href.replace(location.hash,”")) +’”&media=”+$(‘#fullResImage’).attr(‘src’);

    jQuery(‘.pp_social’).append(“<div class=’pinterest’ ><a href=’”+ href +”‘ class=’pin-it-button’ count-layout=’horizontal’ target=’_blank’><img border=’0′ src=’http://assets.pinterest.com/images/PinExt.png’ title=’Pin It’ /></a></div>”);
}
```

for complete description, please visit my tutorial page.

[Add Pinterest to social media icons in prettyPhoto](http://websolstore.com/how-to-add-pinterest-to-social-media-icons-in-prettyphoto/)

i am sure it will help you a lot.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how the above solution could have worked, since `{path}` never gets replaced in `settings.social_tools`.

The only way was to declare a global and assign it the media url depending on case (image/video/etc) and finally update the `.pp_social` div

I am sure it can be done more elegantly, but this is more of a quick patch and it just works.

For someone else who is looking for a solution, here is the [modified prettyphoto javascript](http://themesupport.webylabs.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/jquery.prettyPhoto.js)

Answer (score 1):

This is the only way it will work.

Don't use an ID for the images because each time you want to pin an image it will take every time the first image with the ID on your webpage.

See below for code:

```
$('.prettyPhoto').prettyPhoto({ changepicturecallback: onPictureChanged, });

function onPictureChanged() {

  var href= "http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=" + encodeURIComponent(location.href.replace(location.hash,"")) +"&media="+$('#pp_full_res').find('img').attr('src');

  jQuery('.pp_social').append("<div class='pinterest' ><a   href='"+ href +"' class='pin-it-button' count-layout='horizontal' target='_blank'><img border='0' src='http://assets.pinterest.com/images/PinExt.png' title='Pin It'/></a></div>");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Changed the code to this and it's now working:

```
<div class="pinterest">
    <a href="http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url='+encodeURIComponent(location.href.replace(location.hash,""))+'&media={path}&description={title}" class="pin-it-button" count-layout="horizontal" target="_blank">
        <img border="0" src="http://assets.pinterest.com/images/PinExt.png" title="Pin It" />
    </a>
</div>
```